# how to migrate from mongodb to gcp datastore

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, migration, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine

So we have large db which we want to move to gcp managed service datastore so it import service is not much functional so is there any other way to migrate that db with my same scheama set.

Comment: You would need to ask GCP for support for this, since it's a managed service.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin Adistambha mentioned, I would highly suggest contacting GCP support through this link [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/). If you do not have a support package with GCP, you can always create a public issue tracker through [here](https://issuetracker.google.com).